# How to calculate the dimension of an infinite direct product of copies of a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, cardinals

Let $F$ be a field and $I$ an arbitrary *infinite* index set. I'd like to know how to calculate the dimension of $\prod_{i\in I}F$.

By the way, I know $\dim(\prod_{i\in I}F)\geqslant 2^{\text{card}(I)}$. Does the equation always hold?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217128/the-dimension-of-vector-space-fx