# The dimension of vector space $F^{X}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

**Here's the problem:**

Let $F$ be field, $X$ an infinite set and $F^{X}$ be the set of all functions $f:X\rightarrow F$. Then $F^{X}$ is a vector space over $F$ (with $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(rf)(x)=rf(x)$ ).

The thing puzzling me is how to prove the equation $\dim_{F}F^{X}=|F|^{|X|}$ because I find it difficult to determine some basis of $F^{X}$ directly. Anyway, any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless $X$ is countable, I think explicitly writing down a basis is going to be a difficult task.

Comment: II think so. Moreover I notice that $F^{X}\cong V^{*}$ where the $V=\sum F$ with index set $X$ is a free vector space over $F$. Then $\dim_{F}F^{X}=\dim_{F}V^{*}$ and we may prove that $\dim_{F}V^{*}=|F|^{|X|}$? Even if my conjecture above is correct, I also try to find a proof which is both direct and simple.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces) could help you.

Comment: Well, I think the problem can be solved by this method. Thanks,@user26857