# Infinite direct product of fields.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and consider the infinite direct product$$F \times F \times F \times F \times \dots,$$i.e. $\prod_{i=0}^\infty F$, i.e. the direct product of a countable number of copies of $F$. The theory of bases for vector spaces shows that this direct product has a basis, and so is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $F$. How many copies of $F$ do I need $($i.e. what is the dimension of this direct product as an $F$-vector space$)$? Is it possible to exhibit this isomorphism between an infinite direct product and an infintie direct sum explicitly?

Comment: Interesting: this question has appeared few times on M.SE in the last days! Same homework? (See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213082/how-to-calculate-the-dimension-of-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-a-fiel#comment2476525_1213082 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217128/the-dimension-of-vector-space-fx)

Comment: Admittedly, this is an extra credit homework question, but I looked at the names of the other users who asked the same question and I do not believe they are in my class. Just a coincidence, I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dimension is the cardinality $|F|^{\aleph_0}$ according to the [Theorem of Erdös-Kaplansky](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_d%27Erd%C5%91s-Kaplansky). See [MO/49551](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces) for a general formula of the dimension of an infinite family of vector spaces. All this belongs to "set-theoretic linear algebra", and no bases can be explicitly written down, since the axiom of choice plays a central role. Probably there are models of ZF where $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \dotsc$ is no direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$; hopefully a set-theorist can add a reference for this.

Comment: It wasn't stated in the question or in this answer, so I'll just state for the record that $\dim(\bigoplus_{\Bbb N}F) = \aleph_0$ (in contrast to the direct product), pretty much by the definition of a direct sum.

Answer (score -2):

To see the difference between infinite direct product and infinite direct sum (both involving countable number of copies) see their concrete realisations:
The vector space of all polynomials in $X$ over $F$, and the vector space of all formal power series (convergent or not) in $X$ over $F$. Now you can see what forms the basis in each case.

Comment: 1) The difference between direct product and direct sum can be directly seen from their construction. 2) Polynomials and power series are no concrete realizations; I would rather say that the underlying vector space of the *$F$-algebra* $F[x]$ resp. $F[[x]]$ is $F^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ resp. $F^{\mathbb{N}}$. Thus, polynomials and power series carry more structure. 3) The notion of convergence doesn't make sense here. 4) You claim that one can see a basis of $F^{\mathbb{N}}$. This is wrong. For example, $\{1,e_1,e_2,\dotsc\}$ is no basis, it generates sequences which are eventually constant.

Comment: @Martin Brandenberg: Thanks for the precision, and pointing out the mistake. Perhaps what I said makes sense only as groups: and not as $F$-algebra. That is they are concrete examples of infinite direct produc as groups and infinite direct sum as groups. Is this correct?