# Cardinality of infinite dimensional vector space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Assume that *F* is an infinite field, *k* is an infinite cardinal, and *V*= {f: *k*→*F*| f is a function} is a vector space.
  Can it be prove proved that |*V*|= dim*V*?
My thought was that we know that|*V*|= max {dim*V*,|*F*|}, so all I need is to prove is that if |*V*|=|*F*|, then also |*F*|=dim*V*. Now, from Konig theorem, if |*V*|=|*F*|, then *k*< cf(|*F*|), so I tried to prove that *k*< cf(|*F*|) is imposible, but i  didn't know how to continue this line of thougt. Has sombodey know how to prove it?

Comment: A useful reference is [**Lectures in Abstract Algebra. Volume II---Linear Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000IC9XL2) by Nathan Jacobson, *Chapter IX. Infinite Dimensional Vector Spaces* (pp. 238-276). See also this [23 July 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=252940) and this [24 July 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=252942) correction/follow-up for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that book. Aren't the links are about the dual space, and not about the originial vector space?

Comment: Perhaps more specific to your question is [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q="direct+product"+"vector+space"+"field"+"cardinality"+"infinite"+site:math.stackexchange.com), which led me in particular to [Infinite direct product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226228) *AND* [Dimension of infinite product of vector spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces\

Comment: I think that my question is actually to prove the erdes-Kaplansky theorem. Am i right, or missing something?

Comment: I've edited my original question. My question is about a set of functions as a vector space, and not about the dual space